# Set dynamic variables in SCSS with npm

Tags: css, npm, sass, scss-mixins

I don't have much experience with npm and SCSS, so I have following question:

I have one SCSS (app.scss) file in which file there are many places which I use one default color for background. My idea is to have a variable $background_color so I can easily change that color. Is it possible and if yes, how ?

Here is the code of my mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('public');

mix.sass('resources/sass/frontend/app.scss', 'css/frontend/frontend.css')
    .sass('resources/sass/backend/app.scss', 'css/backend/backend.css')
    .js('resources/js/frontend/app.js', 'js/frontend.js')
    .js([
        'resources/js/backend/before.js',
        'resources/js/backend/app.js',
        'resources/js/backend/after.js'
    ], 'js/backend/backend.js')
    .extract([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction() || process.env.npm_lifecycle_event !== 'hot') {
    mix.version();
}
```

Comment: I doubt the provided code is relevant. Instead add your SCSS. https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-2

Comment: i have tried that before posting this question, but in the $background_color has not been replaced in the created css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sass allows the use of reusable variables:

```css
$color-blue: #0C4376;
```

to be consumed as follows:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: $color-blue; // variable used here
}
```

https://sass-lang.com/guide